# Flutter PageController deletet automatic my text and the image, how i can save this?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm87f.png)I have a probelm with the PageController. As soon as I enter a text and then change the page and then come back again, it deletes all the information I entered before. How can I fix this?

Here its my Code about de override:

```
class AAddTitleComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AAddTitleComponent> createState() => _AAddTitleComponentState();
}

class _AAddTitleComponentState extends State<AAddTitleComponent>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  TextEditingController vehicleTitleTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController vehiclePSDescriptionTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();

  String downloadUrlImage = '';
  String vehicleID = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  File? image;

  Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

      if (image == null) return;

      final imageTemp = File(image.path);

      setState(() => this.image = imageTemp);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Kein Bild ausgewählt $e');
    }

    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setString(
        'vehicleTitleInfo', vehicleTitleTextEditingController.text.toString());
    await sharedPreferences.setString('image', downloadUrlImage);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    vehicleTitleTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and here its the content:

```
children: [
          SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top),
          SizedBox(height: 64),
          Text("Fahrzeug Titel",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 30)),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          TextField(
            autocorrect: true,
            autofocus: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            controller: vehicleTitleTextEditingController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 0,
                ),
              ),
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              hintText: 'Fahrzeug Titel eingeben',
              labelText: 'Fahrzeug Titel',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              // alignLabelWithHint: false,
            ),
          )
```

as soon as I change the pages it deletes everything for me.

[as soon as I change the pages it deletes everything for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l3QT.png)

Comment: You attached an image, not video.

Comment: how i can upload the video?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this solution based on the assumption that the page controller is used as a bottom navigation system or tab bar navigation system:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key key});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
   return Scaffold(
        .....
   );
}
 @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
 }
```